# NSWindow bind load event for control and logic initialization

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I just started working on an OSX application, first time in objective-c. I need to make a window that will display all the network interfaces available on the computer.

**So far**

- I have an `AppDelegate` that pretty much does nothing
- I have set the `Main nib file base name` to my main window, which is a xib, header and implementation file
- I made my xib window inherit from my class and added the outlets I needed using right-click drag (worked well, I assumed I was correct until then)

**The issue**

I can't seem either override or bind the load event of the window, where I want to load the text in my label.

I've seen some people use a NSWindowController, but I don't think I need this.

**My question**

Is it required to have a `NSWindowController` PLUS a `NSWindow` class? I feel there are too many files for a single window. I have the xib and two .h/.m files... If it's not required, how can I get notified when the window loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question wether you need `NSWindowController`(s) or not depends on the complexity of your application.
If your app is only a small utility using a single window, you might get away with setting up your UI in MainMenu.xib and connect it to some `IBOutlets` in your AppDelegate.

But the above approach gets messy soon when your app becomes more complex. To tame that complexity, you can create dedicated `NSWindowController` classes (e.g. one per window). Those window controllers could manage a hierarchy of child `NSViewControllers` to further split up your complexity.

> If it's not required, how can I get notified when the window loads?

The default Xcode template should have created an AppDelegate.m file. You can add code to initialize your UI in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

At this point the window has been fully loaded and

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

should point to your window instance.

Comment: And you don't need a subclass of NSWindow. When the window loads, `-[NSWindowController windowDidLoad]` is called.